# Is there a simple code to get time zone from Etcetera area

Tags: timezone

I know that The etc area time zone boundaries are meridians 15° apart with Longitude;

eg:
ETC/GMT (-7,7)
ETC/GMT -1 (7,15)
...

so i need write a code with a switch  or a if-else format;

Is there a simple and pretty code to get it with just a single parmeter "longitude"?

Thanks

Comment: In what language?  Have you tried anything yet?  I hope you are aware that these zones have their offsets inverted from the usual convention, and also that they are meant primarily for ships at sea - not for inhabited locations on land.

Comment: FYI - I have a C# implementation [here](https://github.com/mj1856/GeoTimeZone/blob/3.2.0/src/GeoTimeZone/TimeZoneLookup.cs#L162-L184).  If this works for you, let me know and I'll post it as an answer here.

Comment: @MattJohnson i want to use C code to implement it.   WOW your code seems amazing for me. i ll take a look at it.Thanks.